# Борьба с самоочищением ViewModel

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

Сразу после успешного биндинга `EmployeesViewModel` на `DataContext` страницы он очищается.

ViewModel `EmployeesViewModel` наследуется от `BaseViewModel` и содержит методы получения `ObservableCollection<ClinicService.Employee>` от WCF:

```
public class EmployeesViewModel:BaseViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<ClinicService.Employee> Employees{get;set;}

        public EmployeesViewModel()
        { }

        public async void GetEmployees(bool ShowInactive)
        {
              Employees = await Data.WCFConnection.GetEmployeesAsync(true);
        }

    }
```

Сам BaseViewModel - это вариация хорошо знакомого MVVMщикам синглтона, унаследованого от INotifyPropertyChanged

```
public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

 private static BaseViewModel instance;

        public static BaseViewModel Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (instance == null)
                {
                    instance = new BaseViewModel();
                }
                return instance;
            }
        }

        protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string property)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public virtual bool IsValid()
        {
            return true;
        }
```

Назначение происходит следующим образом:

```
public partial class Employees : Page
    {
        EmployeesViewModel emv = new EmployeesViewModel();
        public Employees()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            emv.GetEmployees(true);  //emv успешно получил 16 элементов
            this.DataContext = emv;  //emv показывает полученные элементы (их даже видно в DataGrid, если поставить brakepoint)
        }                            //emv очищается после окончания метода, несмотря на то, что объявлен в классе
       ...
   }
```

Я не буду показывать View, потому что дело явно не в нем.

**Вопрос: Почему очищается `emv.Employees` сразу после завершения конструктора страницы?**

*P.S. Интуитивно чувствую, что косяк в жизненном цикле ViewModel... но нигде не вижу криминала.*

**UPD:** Поправил объявление `Employees` в `EmployeesViewModel`

**UPD2:** Дальнейшая локализация показала, что `Employees` очищается сразу после выполнения асинхронного метода `GetEmployees` в `EmployeesViewModel`, хотя внутри метода по данным трассировки `Employees` заполняется:

```
 public async void GetEmployees(bool ShowInactive)
        {
            Employees = await Data.WCFConnection.GetEmployeesAsync(true);
        }
```

**UPD3:** Для упрощения отказался от класса `BaseModelView`, перенес его функциональность в `EmployeesViewModel`, который теперь выглядит так:

```
  public class EmployeesViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged 
    {

        private  ObservableCollection<ClinicService.Employee> employees;

        public ObservableCollection<ClinicService.Employee> Employees
        {   
            get
                { 
                    return this.employees;
                }

            set 
                {
                    if (value != this.employees)
                    { 
                        this.employees = value; 
                        NotifyPropertyChanged();
                    }
                }
        }

        public EmployeesViewModel()
        { 

        }

        public async Task GetEmployees(bool ShowInactive)
        {
            employees = await Data.WCFConnection.GetEmployeesAsync(true);
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }



        private static EmployeesViewModel instance;

        public static EmployeesViewModel Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (instance == null)
                {
                    instance = new EmployeesViewModel();
                }
                return instance;
            }
        }
```

Теперь проблема в том, что при вызове `NotifyPropertyChanged` событие `PropertyChanged`  всегда остается `null`.

**Вопрос закрыт**

Причиной проблемы являлось то, что привязка к данным осуществлялась до момента завершения их получения в асинхронном методе. Генерация события   `public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;` по завершении работы асинхронного метода в `EmployeesViewModel` решило проблему:

```
 public async Task GetEmployees(bool ShowInactive)
        {
            employees = await Data.WCFConnection.GetEmployeesAsync(true);
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Employees");
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Думаю, проблема не в этом. В `EmployeesViewModel` `Employees` — поле, а не свойство. Биндинг к полям в WPF не работает.

Сделайте `Employees` нестатическим публичным полем.

---

Следующая ошибка:

```
emv.GetEmployees(true); // (1) async-функция
this.DataContext = emv; // (2)
```

Что происходит? Строка (1) запускает async-функцию получения результатов. На момент, когда эта строка отработала, `emv.Empoyees` всё ещё `null`. Затем строка (2) привязывает `DataContext`. Срабатывают триггеры, осуществляется привязка по текущему значению `Empoyees` — `null`. Через некоторое время `async`-функция заканчивается, присваивает `Empoyees` ненулевое значение. Но поскольку в новом коде всё ещё не реализовано `INotifyPropertyChanged`, это новое значение никто не видит.

Делайте правильно:

```
ObservableCollection<ClinicService.Employee> employees;
public ObservableCollection<ClinicService.Employee> Employees
{
    get { return employees; }
    set { if (value != employees) { employees = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }}
}
```

---

То, что async-функция «завершилась» (то есть, начала выполняться следующая строчка после вызова функции), ещё не значит, что код самой функции отработал до конца. Ваша функция скорее всего ожидает в `await` и завершится позже. (Это, кстати, причина того, почему `async void`-функции не рекомендуются, используйте `async Task`.)

---

Кстати, ваш метод `RaisePropertyChanged` должен бы пользоваться атрибутом `[CallerMemberName]`, как, например, в примере [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (см. класс `DemoCustomer`).

---

Всё ещё неправильно. На этот раз строка `employees = await Data.WCFConnection.GetEmployeesAsync(true);`. Присвоение полю не генерирует `PropertyChanged`. Замените это на `Employees = ...`.

Comment: Да, это большая ошибка, но дело, как ни странно, не в ней. Поменял в EmployeesViewModel поле на свойство:  public ObservableCollection<ClinicService.Employee> Employees{get;set;}  но ничего не изменилось

Comment: @AnatolyNikolaev: Всё ещё неправильно. Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Кое что изменил (см.UPD3) Не совсем понятно, как на данном этапе на ситуацию влияет сеттер. Ведь я получаю данные сразу в приватное поле, а DataGrid по идее только читает свойство через Get. Получается до тех пор, пока я не начну изменять значения в самом DataGrid мне этот сеттер не понадобится...

Comment: @AnatolyNikolaev: Следующая итерация :) Обновил ответ.

Comment: Да я уже понял) Переделал на:  employees = await Data.WCFConnection.GetEmployeesAsync(true);
NotifyPropertyChanged("Employees");  Решило проблему. Не хочу изнутри класса писать через сеттер)) Огромное спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @AnatolyNikolaev: Пожалуйста!